# Collapse 3 Text Colums into 1 within a wide Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reduction

I have a dataset with one data type spread across multiple columns. I'd like to reduce these to a single column. I have a function that accomplishes this, but its a cumbersome process and I'm hoping there's a cleaner way to accomplish this. Here's a toy sample of my data:

```
UID    COMPANY    EML    MAI   TEL
273    7UP        nan    nan   TEL
273    7UP        nan    MAI   nan
906    WSJ        nan    nan   TEL
906    WSJ        EML    nan   nan
736    AIG        nan    MAI   nan
```

What I'd like to get to:

```
UID    COMPANY   CONTACT_INFO
273    7UP       MT
906    WSJ       ET
736    AIG       M
```

I've solved this by writing a function that converts `EML`, `MAI` or `TEL` to a prime number, aggregates the results then converts the sum into the constituent contact types. This works, and is reasonably quick. Here's a sample:

```
def columnRedux(df):
    newDF = df.copy()
    newDF.fillna('-', inplace=True)
    newDF['CONTACT_INFO'] = newDF['EML'] + newDF['MAI'] + newDF['TEL']
    newDF.replace('EML--', 7, inplace=True)
    newDF.replace('-MAI-', 101, inplace=True)
    newDF.replace('--TEL', 1009, inplace=True)

    small = newDF.groupby(['UID', 'COMPANY'], as_index=False)['CONTACT_INFO'].sum()

    small.replace(7, 'E', inplace=True)
    small.replace(101, 'M', inplace=True)
    small.replace(108, 'EM', inplace=True)
    small.replace(1009, 'T', inplace=True)
    small.replace(1016, 'ET', inplace=True)
    small.replace(1110, 'MT', inplace=True)
    small.replace(1117, 'EMT', inplace=True)

    return small

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'EML' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'EML', np.nan, np.nan, 'EML', np.nan, np.nan, 'EML', 'EML', np.nan],
    'MAI' : [np.nan, 'MAI', np.nan, np.nan, 'MAI', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'MAI', np.nan, np.nan, 'MAI'],
    'COMPANY' : ['7UP', '7UP', 'UPS', 'UPS', 'UPS', 'WSJ', 'WSJ', 'TJX', 'AIG', 'CDW', 'HEB', 'HEB'],
    'TEL' : ['TEL', np.nan, 'TEL', np.nan, np.nan, 'TEL', np.nan, 'TEL', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'UID' : [273, 273, 865, 865, 865, 906, 906, 736, 316, 458, 531, 531]},
    columns=['UID', 'COMPANY', 'EML', 'MAI', 'TEL'])

cleanDF = columnRedux(df1)
```

My issue is that I have several data sets, each with its own set of "wide" columns. Some have 5+ columns to be reduced. Hard coding the conversions for all of the variations is not trivial. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not the "nicest" solution. But one would be to use a simple groupby and condition the included elements:

```
df = df.groupby(['UID','COMPANY'])[['EML','MAI','TEL']]\
    .apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted([i[0] for y in x.values for i in y if pd.notnull(i)])))\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={0:'CONTACT_INFO'})
```

Or an alternative would be to convert the grouped dataframes to type str and replace the strings and sum. Quite readable I'd say.

```
m = {
    'nan':'',
    'EML':'E',
    'MAI':'M',
    'TEL':'T'
}

df = df.groupby(['UID','COMPANY'])[['EML','MAI','TEL']]\
       .apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).replace(m).sum().sum())\
       .reset_index()\
       .rename(columns={0:'CONTACT_INFO'})
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = '''\
UID    COMPANY    EML    MAI   TEL
273    7UP        nan    nan   TEL
273    7UP        nan    MAI   nan
906    WSJ        nan    nan   TEL
906    WSJ        EML    nan   nan
736    AIG        nan    MAI   nan'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+').replace('NaN',np.nan)

# use a nested list comprehension to flatten the array and remove nans.
df = df.groupby(['UID','COMPANY'])[['EML','MAI','TEL']]\
    .apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted([i[0] for y in x.values for i in y if pd.notnull(i)])))\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={0:'CONTACT_INFO'})

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
UID  COMPANY  CONTACT_INFO
273      7UP            MT
736      AIG             M
906      WSJ            ET
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is great. I also wasn't aware that I could cleanly create a DF from a string in this manner. Thanks for your help. I've awarded this as the answer. It addresses all of my questions and I believe you were the first to answer.

Comment: @Lenwood Yes, I might have been first. But I'd say you should vote as accepted the one that suits you most. The other solutions are quite smart too :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this:

```
(df1.set_index(['UID','COMPANY']).notnull() * df1.columns[2:].str[0])\
.sum(level=[0,1]).sum(1).reset_index(name='CONTACT_INFO')
```

Output:

```
   UID COMPANY CONTACT_INFO
0  273     7UP           MT
1  865     UPS          EMT
2  906     WSJ           ET
3  736     TJX            T
4  316     AIG            M
5  458     CDW            E
6  531     HEB           EM
```

Split up for @AntonvBR:

```
df2 = df1.set_index(['UID','COMPANY'])
df_out  = ((df2.notnull() * df2.columns.str[0])
           .sum(level=[0,1]) #consolidate rows of contact info to one line
           .sum(1)  #sum across columns to create one column
           .reset_index(name='CONTACT_INFO'))
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   UID COMPANY CONTACT_INFO
0  273     7UP           MT
1  865     UPS          EMT
2  906     WSJ           ET
3  736     TJX            T
4  316     AIG            M
5  458     CDW            E
6  531     HEB           EM
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `dot` create the new columns after `groupby` `first`

```
s=df.groupby(['UID','COMPANY'],as_index=False).first()

s['CONTACT_INFO']=s[['EML','MAI','TEL']].notnull().dot(s.columns[2:].str[0])
s.dropna(1)
Out[349]: 
   UID COMPANY CONTACT_INFO
0  273     7UP           MT
1  736     AIG            M
2  906     WSJ           ET
```

Comment: Ok yep, now we are talking. Don't know why you use `s` though as that would imply you got a series. And dropna(1) isn't 100% stable. :). Lovely solution.